# register system in python 3 cant identify already taken usernames

Tags: python

I started learning python(and coding in general) a couple of weeks ago and I am having struggle in a project I trying to make. In part of the project I am trying to make a register and login system, everything went fine expect the 'username already taken' part in the register section.
No matter what I do, the code just keep allowing registering even if the username already taken(You can register with "x" username, and right after registering again with "x" username).
I will appreciate any kind of help!(and sorry for the english :) )

```
    import re
    Users = open('Users.txt', mode = 'a')
    Hquestion = input("\t\t  If you already registered please press Y, if you need to register 
    please press N")  
    def register():
        if Hquestion == "N" or Hquestion == "n":
            with open('Logindata.txt', mode = 'a') as logindata:
                firstname = input('please write your first name(only a-zA-Z allowed): ')            
                username = input('Enter Username : ')
                with open('Users.txt', mode = 'r') as userdata:
                    if username in userdata:
                        print("username already taken!")
                        return register()
                password = input ('Enter Password (using only a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*. min 8 characters) : ' )
                passpattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*()-+=?/".,{}\;:~]{8,}')
                namepattern = re.findall('[0-9!@#$%^&*()-+=?/".,{}\;:~]',firstname)
                while not passpattern.match(password):
                    print("Your password is invalid. Please make sure you password is atleast 8 characters long!\n")
                    return register()
                if namepattern:
                    print("Please use only a-z A-Z characters for first and last name!\n")
                    return register()
                Users.write(f'{username}\n')
                Users.close()
                logindata.write(f'{username} ')
                logindata.write(f'{password} ')
                logindata.write(f'{firstname}\n')
    def login():
        if Hquestion == "Y" or Hqeustion == "y":
            loginuser = input('Write your username: ')
            loginpass = input('Write your password: ')
            for user_pass in open('Logindata.txt', mode = 'r').readlines():
                loginsplit = user_pass.split()
                if loginuser == loginsplit[0] and loginpass == loginsplit[1]:
                    print("You have succsesfuly loged in! Enjoy shoping in Tomer's Shop!")
                    return
                else:
                    print("Your username or password wrong, please try again")
                    return login() 
    register()
    login()
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations), python will iterate containers that do not implement `__contains__`. The file object is one of those containers.

That means that your membership test `if username in userdata:` will iterate the file line by line until username is found. The thing is, that's the *full* line, including newline. A quick test shows that username without newline is False and reads through the entire file

```
>>> # create test file
>>> open("users.txt", "w").write("Alice\nBob\nChuck\n")
16
>>> username = "Bob"
>>> f = open("users.txt")
>>> username in f
False
>>> f.read()
''
```

But adding the newline fixes the problem

```
>>> f = open("users.txt")
>>> username + "\n" in f
True
>>> f.read()
'Chuck\n'
```

Comment: @tomerkeinan - Accept the answer if it works for you so that other's know the question is done. Programming tip: Try to whittle problems down to small bits of code you can experiment with, like in my example. Many problems are fixed just doing that.

Comment: Thank you, was my first post and didnt really know what is neccessery :)